# Parsing Datetime from a string without errors

Tags: c#, datetime

I am new to C# so its quite possible that this has a fairly simple solution but I haven't found anything I'd consider elegant. If you need any additional information or are confused about what I'm asking in any way, let me know and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

Currently the way create validation rules (for when someone submits a form), like so:

```
new ValidationRuleInstance<DetailsPresenter>(
    new IsValidDateRule<DetailsPresenter>(m => m.StartDate, "StartDate"),
    new ValidationRuleInterpretation(Severity.Failure, "StartDateMustBeValid", "Must enter valid start date (dd/mm/yyyy)")
),
```

What I'm attempting to do is create a Validation rule to check if the date that I was give occurred in the past. What I tired is this:

```
new ValidationRuleInstance<DetailsPresenter>(
    new FailIfTrueRule<DetailsPresenter>(m => (DateTime.Parse(m.StartDate).AddDays(1) < DateTime.Now) ,"StartDate"),
    new ValidationRuleInterpretation(Severity.Failure, "StartDateCannotBeInThePast", "Your start date cannot be in the past")
),
```

This is works... Most of the time (P.S. I'm adding one day so that entering the current date doesn't produce an error).

The problem is that if someone submits a String that cannot be parsed into a date time object (eg. 725/2011 instead of 7/25/2011) the whole thing blows up.

I have tried using TryParse, however that returns a Boolean not a Time-Date object.

Am I going to have to write my own method to parse a String and always return a DateTime object? Can I catch the exception and ignore it? (there is a separate rule already in place for checking if the string is valid)

Comment: the TryParse does return an DateTime object, it is the second param as an out param. you an use is as described on [MSDN DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx#Y100). it like DateTime.TryParse("7/25/2011", out date)

Comment: Just a comment: rather than doing `.AddDays(1) < DateTime.Now`, you could just use `< DateTime.Today`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason you can't use a multi-line block of code in a lambda. You just have to enclose the code in brackets and issue explicit `return` statements, rather than just specifying a single expression that implicitly returns its value.

```
new ValidationRuleInstance<DetailsPresenter>(
    new FailIfTrueRule<DetailsPresenter>(m => 
{
    DateTime value;

    if(DateTime.TryParse(m.StartDate, out value))
    {
        return value.AddDays(1) < DateTime.Now;
    }
    else // parsing failed, return whatever value is appropriate
    {

    }
} ,"StartDate"),
    new ValidationRuleInterpretation(Severity.Failure, "StartDateCannotBeInThePast", "Your start date cannot be in the past")
),
```

Comment: Very cool! The examples I've seen so far, have only been one liners but that makes sense.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to write the lambda as follows:

```
m => { DateTime d; return DateTime.TryParse(m.StartDate, out d) ? d.AddDays(1) < DateTime.Now : true; }
```

Comment: Should that be `false` at the end?

Comment: @Jon Egerton: The rule is `FailIfTrue` so I assumed it should return `true` for an invalid date, because then it will fail. The OP may replace it with whatever value is appropriate. :)

Comment: I liked your answer and will probably use it, but Adam's answer taught me something I didn't know and answered the question, so he gets the brownie points :P.

Comment: @Sumason: no worries, it's fine. Do note that my version is also a multi-statement lambda; I just didn't put line breaks in it.